# Suppress "method never used locally" warning with JUnitParams

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, ide, tdd

I am using junitparams to write my test cases, but I don't like unnecessary warnings in my code.

In case of junitparams, a method that is used as a test-data source gives following warning.

> The method getOddNumbers() from the type XTest is never used locally

I want to suppress this warning, but I don't want to use @SuppressWarnings("unused") because i am using this method in @Parameters(method="getOddNumbers") annotation.

Please find below dummy source code and screenshot of the warning :-

```
package com.x.test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner;
import junitparams.Parameters;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class XTest {

    @Test
    @Parameters(method="getEvenNumbers")
    public void isEven(int value) throws Exception {
        assertTrue(value % 2 == 0);
    }

    @Test
    @Parameters(method="getOddNumbers")
    public void isOdd(int value) throws Exception {
        assertFalse(value % 2 == 0);
    }

    private static Object[] getEvenNumbers() {

        return new Object[] { 
                new Object[] { 2 },
                new Object[] { 4 },
                new Object[] { -6 },
                new Object[] { -10 }
        };
    }

    private static Object[] getOddNumbers() {

        return new Object[] { 
                new Object[] { 1 },
                new Object[] { 3 },
                new Object[] { -7 },
                new Object[] { -11 }
        };
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Check error/warnings settings in Eclipse and see if there's options for just the test files versus source files.

Comment: @NESPowerGlove : As suggested, i checked the settings, but not able to find options.

Comment: Don't know then, other IDEs I have used have this option.